# ngx-translate "Http failure response for /assets/i18n/... 0 OK" error on Ionic 7

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngx-translate, ionic7

The error doesn't happen on the development server (ionic serve), it occurs when I try to test the app on the device after build.

My `app.module.ts` is:

```
...
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, SideMenuComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      defaultLanguage: 'pt-BR',
      loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
          deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

[image: Console]

Thanks in advance.

Ionic: v7.1
Angular: v16.0.0

I also tried this on loader factory:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

But nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

[image: reference image showing angular.json]

Add `src/assets/i18n` under 'assets' in angular.json